# converting data type stored in list into Date R

Tags: r, datetime, lapply

I have a list `data`.

and there are several data frames in each.

```
[[1]]
ID: int [1:100] ...
Date: Factor w/ ...
days: num [1:100] ...
[[2]]
ID: int [1:100] ...
Date: Factor w/ ...
```

like this.

And I want to convert that factor to Date format. 
I thought about 
 
unlist the list - changing format - making it to list again.

But I have no idea how to do that..

```
sapply(data, function(x) x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date))
```

This doesn't work. It only returns Date and doesn't change the data type.
Is there any fast way to convert that format?

I can solve this by using for loop.

```
for(i in 1:2){
data[[i]]$Date <- as.Date(data[[i]]$Date)}
```

But I would like to use sapply or lappy.

Comment: *This doesn't work* ... how exactly? I'd think you would be better with `lapply` or `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` than just `sapply`.

Comment: Your function isn't `return`ing `x` after altering it.

Comment: As @thelatemail said, you need to return the list after altering something in it: `lapply(data, function(x) x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date); return(x))` To give us a better chance to solve your problem, please either provide an example of your data using `dput()`, or construct an example yourself using random numbers while making sure the classes used are the same in your real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to transform `factor` into `character` at first and then to `Date` format. The most easiest way is to use `lubridate` package. `ymd` transform `character` vectors of format e.g. `2018-11-22` into  Year-Month-Date datetime object. Please pay attention to lambda-function body, after the change of the data frame it is typed `x`, which is a shortcut of `return(x)`.  See the code below:

```
library(lubridate)

# simulation of data
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:100, 
  Date = as.factor(sample(seq(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd("2018-12-01"), 1), 100)),
  days = sample(100))

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:100, 
  Date = as.factor(sample(seq(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd("2018-12-01"), 1), 100, replace =TRUE)))

dfs <- list(df1, df2)

str(dfs)

# List of 2
# $ :'data.frame':  100 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ ID  : int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   ..$ Date: Factor w/ 100 levels "2018-01-06","2018-01-10",..: 17 89 40 2 84 46 58 62 66 43 ...
#   ..$ days: int [1:100] 50 4 19 6 33 47 95 25 13 5 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  100 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ ID  : int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   ..$ Date: Factor w/ 87 levels "2018-01-03","2018-01-04",..: 3 30 61 6 78 34 5 71 49 55 ...

# handling the data
dfs_2 <- lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  x$Date <- ymd(as.character(x$Date))
  x
})

str(dfs_2)
# List of 2
# $ :'data.frame':  100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ ID  : int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..$ Date: Date[1:100], format: "2018-03-10" "2018-10-25" "2018-11-25" ...
#  ..$ days: int [1:100] 7 99 75 91 30 78 9 82 15 37 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  100 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ ID  : int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..$ Date: Date[1:100], format: "2018-05-30" "2018-05-20" "2018-05-13" ...
```